# how to find word in text file and print the line its on python

Tags: python, text

I am trying to read a text file and find a specific word from it and print the entire line its on

for example, in the following text file:

```
steve 22 london

john 30 paris

alex 19 berlin
```

I want to search for `"john"` and print the entire line:

```
john 30 paris
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, iterating through the lines with a `for` loop:

```
word = "john"
with open("path/to/your/file") as f:
    for line in f:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if word in stripped_line:
            print(line)
```